# If I put equippable items in the dimensional vault, will they retain their current durability?

Tags: one-way-heroics

In one of my previous adventures I died to my sword breaking down at the worst possible moment. I'm now a little more wary about this sort of stuff happening. It seems that shields and armor can also break apart without warning.

Once you do die though, you can put them in your dimensional vault. That doesn't sound like such a good idea if they break down immediately after I equip them, though...

[image]

Comment: IMHO, you should just pick up all the gear you find, and use it till it breaks.  Get in the habit of treating your gear as disposable and you'll (probably) live longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting in equipment leaves it at the durability that it goes into the vault with. That doesn't sound too hot, but there's some bonuses to this though.

By spending Hero Points, you can repair any piece of equipment in the vault. The cost in points is relative to the value of the item, though, and how much you're repairing. So it can be pretty pricey for the stuff you really want to preserve, but in the long run this is the best way to fix stuff up.

There's only a few other ways to repair items in the game:

- Scrolls of Repair restore up to 50 durability to your equipped weapon and armor. They're fairly rare, and usually only found in shops for 6000+ silver.
- Shield Repair Kits are the same as scrolls of repair, but only work on shields. They're somewhat cheaper but still relatively rare and have a weight of 2.
- Scrolls of Jerryrigging will fully repair your equipped weapon and armor, but also gives them an enchantment called "Jerryrigged" which increases their degradation rate significantly. Much more useful for emergency measures on an intermediate weapon than it is on something really special, unless you know how to remove enchantments.
- Very rarely, you might run into an NPC called a Blacksmith (I found my first one this morning). They will fully repair either your equipped weapon or armor or shield in exchange for silver. Like with the Hero Points repair, it's relative to the value of the item and how much durability is to be repaired. He can repair unidentified items though between the unknown value of the item and the unknown durability amount, it's not quite a reliable way to determine the durability unless you've previously price-ID'd your equipment in a shop.

Just as your equipment stays in its mostly broken state when you put it in the vault, if you take it out and repair it, putting it back in the vault will have you a nicely fixed item. It's more common to rely on stockpiling scrolls of repair (again through the vault) - they don't cause penalties like jerryrigging, they're more common than blacksmiths (unless you have a particularly nice seed), and they can repair both a weapon and an armor at once.